# Table Variable and Table-Valued Function equivalent in PostgreSQL

Tags: sql, postgresql

I need to create a function in PostgreSQL for the following :

- Query multiple tables based on a business logic (all result sets return the same type of data)
- Compile all result sets into one table and return that table

  Is it possible to accomplish this without using the temp tables in PostgreSQL?

  I currently do this in Microsoft SQL server using Table Variables, below is a sample function:

---

```
create  FUNCTION test(@search_in nvarchar(500))

RETURNS @data_table TABLE
( 
    item_id int, 
    item_type nvarchar(1), 
    first_name nvarchar(100), 
    last_name nvarchar(100))
) AS
BEGIN
    -- from first table
    if charindex('search_in_authors', @search_in) > 0
        insert into @data_table
        select item_id, 'a', first_name, last_name
        from authors
        where first_name = 'james'

    -- from second table
    if charindex('search_in_editors', @search_in) > 0

        insert into @data_table
        select item_id, 'e', first_name, last_name
        from editors
        where first_name = 'james'

    -- from third table
    if charindex('search_in_publishers', @search_in) > 0
        insert into @data_table
        select item_id, 'p', first_name, last_name
        from publishes
        where first_name = 'james'

    -- there could be more like these based on the business logic...

    (...)

    -- finally return the records compiled in @data_table

    RETURN

END
```

---

Sample calls to the function:

```
select * from dbo.test('search_in_authors')

select * from dbo.test('search_in_authors, search_in_editors')

select * from dbo.test('search_in_authors, search_in_editors,search_in_publishers ')
```

---

Are there any options in PostgreSQL to achieve this other than using a temp table ?

Thanks,
San

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`RETURN QUERY`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-control-structures.html#PLPGSQL-STATEMENTS-RETURNING) to add the result of various queries to the output.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.testf() 
RETURNS TABLE(id INTEGER, name text)
STABLE  
AS $$
  DECLARE

  BEGIN
    RETURN QUERY select 1 as id, 'abc' as name;

    RETURN QUERY select 2 as id, 'def' as name;

    RETURN QUERY select 3 as id, 'xyz' as name;

    -- Final return as set is now complete.
    return;

  END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;


select * from public.testf();

 id | name
----+------
  1 | abc
  2 | def
  3 | xyz
(3 rows)
```